# importing ecoinvent 3.2 with brightway

Tags: brightway

I am having some trouble importing Ecoinvent 3.2 with Brightway2, I was following the [example notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2/raw/default/notebooks/IO%20-%20importing%20Ecoinvent.ipynb):

```
from brightway2 import *
fp = 'D:\LCAdb\e_3.2_cutoff_lci\datasets'
projects.set_current("myproject")
bw2setup()
ei = SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(fp, "ecoinvent 3.2 cutoff")
```

I get a warning message that seems to block the import process

> C:\Users\@@@\Anaconda3\envs\bw3\lib\site-packages\bw2data\project.py:157:
>   UserWarning:
>   ***Read only project***
>
> This project is being used by another process and no writes can be
>   made until:
>       1. You close the other program, or switch to a different project, *and*
>       2. You call `projects.enable_writes` *and* get the response `True`.
>
> ```
> If you are **sure** that this warning is incorrect, call
> `projects.enable_writes(force=True)` to enable writes.
> ```
>
> warnings.warn(READ_ONLY_PROJECT)

if I run

```
projects.enable_writes(force=True)
```

I get another a persmission error

> PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 projects.enable_writes(force=True)
>
> C:\Users\@@@\Anaconda3\envs\bw3\lib\site-packages\bw2data\project.py
>   in enable_writes(self, force)
>       234         """Enable writing for the current project."""
>       235         if force:
>   --> 236             os.remove(os.path.join(self.dir, "write-lock"))
>       237         self.read_only = not self._lock.acquire(timeout = 0.05)
>       238         if not self.read_only:
>
> PermissionError: [WinError 32] El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo
>   porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso:
>   'C:\Users\@@@\AppData\Local\pylca\Brightway3\myproject.4da39212894ad06eb7c95810f8a2a6b0\write-lock'

the winerror translated would be something like "the process does not have access to the file because the file is being used by other process"

I do not have other Brightway environments running at the same time and I have recently updated Brightway2 so I do not know where the problem may be. Any ideas?

thanks!

UPDATE1: I have installed brightway2 in a different computer and I have found the same warning message. Despite the message, the import seems to be correct. once the database is loaded and written, if I open the project again the database is still there.

In the previous laptop the process of importing seems to be too much for the machine (an ASUS S56CB with windows 10 and 6 GB RAM). After 40 min waiting for the result I usually despair and kill it. I will give a try reinstalling python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [how do I resolve errors about read-only projects?](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/faq.html#how-do-i-resolve-errors-about-read-only-projects).

The locking in Brightway2 is done with the [fasteners](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fasteners) library. If you have two python interpreters running, or don't exit a ipython notebook correctly (you should shutdown or restart a kernel before closing the process completely), there will be a lock file in the project directory, and you will get errors about read-only projects. By the way, just closing a ipython notebook is not enough to shut down the python kernel or release the lock.

It is difficult to diagnose why these errors could be occurring with what you have reported. Try the following:

1) See if you can import ecoinvent into a new project.

2) Try restarting your computer.

3) If you can't get anything to work, you can delete the file `C:\Users\@@@\AppData\Local\pylca\Brightway3\myproject.4da39212894ad06eb7c95810f8a2a6b0\write-lock` in the command line or in an explorer window.

4) Do what @Mpa suggest in the next answer, and set `projects.read_only = False`.

Comment: Thanks! I have created from scratch new projects and restarted the laptop with the same result. I have also tried erasing the "lock" file manually. The thing is this file is created again when I use `projects.set_current('myproject')` the lock file is created again and then the system does not let me erase it (either using the command line or the explorer window).

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this in the past, surely because of the reasons @Chris evoked.

You can use `projects.read_only = False` to force-write data. Please make sure that this is really what you want to do. You will *not* want to do this, for example, if you are accessing the same project through two different kernels that may try to write data at the same time.